# Robolectric reactive blockingFirst() somtimes hang

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, robolectric

This test seems fine and works fine.

However, occasionally, it takes forever at the method blockingFirst().

```
@Test
fun test_getScenarioModel() {

    doReturn(MockDownloader({ File("abc.zip") })).whenever(downloaderFactory).newDownloader(
        fileStore = any(),
        zipUrl = anyString(),
        resourceMappingModel = anyOrNull()
    )

    whenever(fileStore.scenarioFile)
        .thenReturn(null)
        .thenReturn(scenarioJsonFile)

    val actual = scenarioProvider.getScenario().blockingFirst()

    val inOrder = inOrder(fileStore, downloaderFactory)

    inOrder.verify(fileStore).scenarioFile
    inOrder.verify(downloaderFactory).newDownloader(any(), anyString(), anyOrNull())

    assertNotNull(actual)
    assertNotNull(actual.result)
}
```

getScenario looks like this:

```
fun getScenario(): Observable<ResultOrException<File>> {
    return scenarioModelResultSubject
        .doOnNext {
            logForDebug { "getScenarioModel(), doOnNext - uniqueId : $uniqueId, result : $it" }
        }
        .doOnError {
            logForDebug { "getScenarioModel(), doOnError - uniqueId : $uniqueId, result : $it" }
        }
        .doOnComplete {
            logForDebug { "getScenarioModel(), doOnComplete" }
        }
        .doOnSubscribe {
            scenarioModelRequestSubject.onNext(scenarioRequestId.get().toString())
        }
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with this test.
Maybe robolectric issue?
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3721

If I run it multiple times then it always hang.
I set timeout and attaching error log:

```
Error Message

org.junit.runners.model.TestTimedOutException: test timed out after 10000 milliseconds
Stacktrace

org.junit.runners.model.TestTimedOutException: test timed out after 10000 milliseconds
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.BlockingBaseObserver.blockingGet(BlockingBaseObserver.java:71)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.blockingFirst(Observable.java:5121)
    at com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_getScenarioModel(InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.kt:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:601)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Standard Output

[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_getResourceMetaFileFromRemote: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_downloadMediaFiles: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_getScenarioMetaFileFromCache: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_downloadMediaFilesFailInThird: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_getScenarioModel: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_getScenarioModelFromFileCache: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_getResourceMetaFileFailed: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_getResourceMetaFileFromCache: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_getScenarioMetaFileFromServer: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
[Robolectric] com.mycommyhome.android.interactivemedia.manager.InteractiveMediaResourceManagerTest.test_unacceptableVersion: sdk=25; resources=binary
W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /home/www/data/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/com.mycommycom2.android_myandroid_PR_auto-test-beta-me-pr-large-2/build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/betaReleaseUnitTest/packageBetaReleaseUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_ Binary XML file line #2525
I/MonitoringInstr: Instrumentation started!
I/MonitoringInstr: Setting context classloader to 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04', Original: 'org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.SandboxClassLoader@2c43ae04'
```

Comment: Could you run it in debug mode, pause the threads and see what's going on? Could be a [Roboelectric bug](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3721).

Comment: I am now running it multiple times in debug mode. How can I pause the threads?